# How to tell hibernate to generate database automatically?

Tags: java, hibernate, schema

My hibernate.cfg.xml is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>

        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>

        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernateSimpleDB</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>

        <property name="transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransactionFactory</property>

        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>

        <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</property>

        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <mapping resource="com/masterhibernate/SimpleHibernateDemo/Person.hbm.xml"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I expect hibernate to create database `hibernateSimpleDB` automatically.
But it doesn't do that.

I know that it will create tables automatically but I want to create database and tables automatically.

Is it possible?

Comment: Add with "database" you mean schema?

Comment: Yes I mean schema by word database

Comment: I don't know whether this is possible. Because then Hibernate would also have to create the database user including password etc.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out http://mojo.codehaus.org/hibernate3-maven-plugin/hbm2ddl-mojo.html

And to create tables.

Check this Hibernate properties.

```
             <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
```

This is the line that make the magic:

```
                        <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
```

Comment: Yes that generates the tables and related meta data; the OP is asking about the -database- those tables will be created in.

Comment: Ok but the question here would be, how many times the guy expect to create the schema?. I never have to worry about to let Hibernate to create the schema because is something that I do just one time per machine.

Comment: Still, it does not answer his question does it?

Comment: "but I want to create database and tables automatically.

Is it possible?" I told him how to create tables.